# Flags to finish background Activities are not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

EDITED WITH ONE (HALF) SOLUTION AT THE END OF THE POST

I have the next logic in my **`MainActivity.class`**:

```
if(SaveSharePreferences.getUserEmail().length == 0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); //Closing MainActivity
} else {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
    finish(); //Closing MainActivity
}
```

So in the **`LoginActivity.class`**:

```
...
public void login() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); //Closing LoginActivity
}
...
```

The main problem to handle the `Activities` is that my `MainMenu.class` contains a `ViewPager` with three tabs, and is in this different tabs (`Fragments`) where I choose go to one deeper `Activity` or another.

In one of these Fragments I have the **`ProfileActivity.class`** option, where I logout. The code is:

```
public void logOut() {    
    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    SaveSharedPreference.clearUser(ProfileActivity.this);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

So it is supposed to be that my activities stack is empty, or it just contains the `MainActivity.class` after the logout, but the next time I do login, the `MainMenu.class` is opened two, three, four times, depending on the current time I´ve logged in.

I´ve tried with `intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)`, also declaring:

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    static Activity mainMenuActivity;
    ...
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        mainMenuActivity = this;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and then closing it from the others, but nothing works. Any solution?

---

**TEMPORAL SOLUTION**

The `Flags` are not working properly either declaring a `public static Activity` and then closing it manually, so I´ve edited the **AndroidManifest.xml** on the following way:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NameOfTheActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

What this `launchMode="sigleTask"` does?

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes
>   the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

I´m avoiding the multiple opening problem that I had before. But some of the activities remain opened and I´m not able to close it, so this is not a definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don want your MainMenu to be in stack, finish it everytime you go to other acitivity and in onBackPress of that activity open it once again if you like. For ex:going from mainmenu to profile do as below in MainMenu

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, ProfileActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And for coming back to mainmenu, do as below in ProfileActivity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
}
```

Comment: I have forgot to mention that I have divided the `MainMenu.class` in three different `Fragments`, so I´m not sure if I can work with your solution.

Comment: Ok, you´ve given me the solution (I think so). I´ll try and I´ll post the result.

Comment: Ok..try it.Happy Coding:)

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It´s seems that one (or more) of the activities remains opened, so every time you login, this two, three, four activities (depending on how many times you make logout/login) make the same, so you login three times at the same time. And the problem is that flags are not closing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
public void logOut() {    
    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    SaveSharedPreference.clearUser(ProfileActivity.this);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

You are asking Android to clear the task **back to the existing instance of `MainActivity`**. The problem is that you don't have an existing instance of `MainActivity` because you already finished it!

In order for this to work, you need to **leave `MainActivity` in the task stack all the time**.

---

NOTE: Also, you don't need `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, this is useless in this situation.